# Allow child panel to handle mouse motion events

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I had a GUI application with the following layout:

```
wxFrame --> wxBoxSizer --> wxImagePanel
```

The wxImagePanel is a custom control (available [here](http://wiki.wxwidgets.org/An_image_panel)).  I've modified it slightly to handle mouse events (using EVT_MOTION) like dragging that allows me to pan the image.

Now, unfortunately, this looks ugly on Windows -- there's a dark gray background.  The recommended approach is to [add a wxPanel](http://wiki.wxwidgets.org/WxFAQ#Why_are_backgrounds_of_windows_ugly.2C_dark_grey_on_Windows.3F_I_want_them_like_my_dialog_boxes.) to the wxFrame -- this makes the ugly background go away.  The app is now layed out like this:

```
wxFrame --> wxBoxSizer --> wxPanel --> wxBoxSizer --> wxImagePanel (a custom control)
```

It looks a lot better, but now the wxPanel I've added is grabbing all the mouse motion events.  They don't get through to the child wxImagePanel, so I can't pan my image anymore.

How can I make sure the mouse motion events make it through to the child wxImagePanel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved the problem by asking on the [wxWidgets forums](http://forums.wxwidgets.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=35264).

Basically, my problem was the wxImagePanel was a child of the wxFrame, whereas it should have been a child of the wxPanel instead.

Answer (score 0):

The normal order of things is

wxFrame --> wxPanel --> wxBoxSizer

I think you would do much better to use this,  like so

wxFrame --> wxImagePanel --> wxBoxSizer

or

wxFrame --> wxPanel --> wxBoxSizer --> wxImagePanel

Comment: I'm using wxFormBuilder, which doesn't seem to allow adding a wxPanel to a wxFrame directly without using a sizer for the frame.